# how to keep sharp turns on model while sub surf modifier is active? (image inside)

Tags: modeling

I would like a sharp turn, not the smoothed round turn that the sub surf modifier causes. Is this possible? Notice the purple line for the mean crease, I would like it to look like that
[image]

Comment: Use `Shift`+`E` while in edit mode while you have the two adjacent edges selected, adding answer (only works on a 3D object) Use loopcuts for 2D ones.

Comment: if it helps, I had solidify modifier on but not applied. I increased the original edge crease weight to 1. Maybe if I applied solidify and then increase the crease weight to 1 on the whole face it would fix it?

Comment: Read my answer.  \The solidify modifier is based off of a 2D mesh, so creases do not work. You need to crease the seam. If you apply the solidify modifier it should work though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what your mesh is like, there are several ways to do this.

**3D Objects:**
You can accomplish this with the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> while in edit mode. Select the edge you would like to crease (the "seam") first, and then press <kbd>1</kbd> or move the cursor until the crease is maxed out.

[image: Edge Crease Method 1]

**2D Objects:**
For two-dimensional objects (planes) you can use Loopcuts to simulate this effect. One of the main drawbacks to this method is your vertex count will be increased. Sadly the Edge Crease option does not work on 2D objects.

In edit mode, hover over the adjacent edges and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then click once and drag towards the seam. Now click again to finish the operation. Repeat for the other side.

[image: Edge Crease Method 2]

Comment: yea that was my main mistake. I had solidify but I hadn't applied it. Shift + e to increase crease weight worked when I applied solidify and then did it to the whole face.